# Problem trying to instantiate Firebase RemoteConfig in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-remote-config

When I try to instantiate RemoteConfig, I get this error and the app crashes (not an error, it just closes).
I've read that a workaround would be :
Workaround: go to your pub cache dir, find MethodCallHandler.java and replace this line:

```
properties.put(
              "inDebugMode", firebaseRemoteConfigInfo.getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled());
```

With this:

```
properties.put("inDebugMode", false);
```

The problem is that this file does not contain any line as it was described. Any ideas?

Full error:

```
E/flutter ( 4211):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/flutter ( 4211):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 4211):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/flutter ( 4211):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter ( 4211):
F/flutter ( 4211): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(942)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
F/libc    ( 4211): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4211 (name_app), pid 4211 (name_app)
```

Answer (score -1):

The workaround didn't work for me but in my case just changing the `platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')` to `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')` in my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`file fixed the problem.
Cheers